# Caching and Playing video

Tags: android, caching, video, streaming, playing

The requirement is to list a Videos thumbnails and on clicking it should play related video into Application. i am able to play url where video is located using Video View. But now i want to implement this thing in a better ways like Watsapp and instagram. If anybody have a good experience in this reference please share with me. I want to play around caching video and playing videos from cache without buffering (Video view is showing buffering bar and very slow in performance user have to wait a lot for starting a Video). Any kind of help will be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Take a look at `AndroidVideoCache` library.

Answer (score 1):

I did it own my own. It's very simple to implement What i do is to download the video with async task along with a progressing seek bar. Once it's downloaded i'll save it in a Folder in my sdcard. We should create a Folder named as Application name so easy to identify and also always available videos with out opening application as well and next time however when i want to watch video again in my application it just check weather it is available in sdcard if yes then play immediately if not then download it. I am happy.